# Why are there lingering open connections in my Heroku-powered Sinatra app's PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, sequel

My web app is located at [www.inflationtrends.com](http://www.inflationtrends.com).

There are several calculators there. The first and third ones access a PostgreSQL database hosted by Heroku. The app itself was made using Sinatra. The app accesses the PSQL database using the Ruby gem Sequel.

In my 'sinatra.rb' file, I connect to the PSQL database using the following code:

```
before do
  db_name = "DATABASE NAME HERE"
  user = "DATABASE USER HERE"
  password = "DATABASE PASSWORD HERE"
  host = "DATABASE HOST NAME HERE"
  port = 5432
  sslmode = 'require'
  DB = Sequel.postgres(
    db_name,
    :user=>user,
    :password=>password,
    :host=>host,
    :port=>port,
    :sslmode=>sslmode
  )
end
```

And I also have an 'after do' block that disconnects from the database when the page loads

```
after do
  DB.disconnect
end
```

Despite the 'DB.disconnect' code, I've noticed that there are still open connections when multiple machines use the app. I notice that the number of 'numbackends' (backend connections?) increases when those multiple clients access the app when I run the following code:

```
DB[
"SELECT *

FROM 
    pg_stat_database 

WHERE 
    datname = "DATABASE NAME HERE;"
].each{|r| p r}
```

I should mention, though, that I have some code like the following within the 'sinatra.rb' file:

```
get '/' do
    @variable = DB[
        "SQL CODE HERE"
    ]
    erb :index
end
```

That code grabs the items for the 'grocery list' in the third calculator. I don't know if that would cause connections to linger. I've tried adding a "DB.disconnect" line after the "erb :index" line, but that didn't seem to affect the number of open connections.

In addition, @variable is called in the "index.erb" file, but I thought that the "DB.disconnect" statement in the "after" loop would take care of it. I even tried adding "DB.disconnect" to the end of the "index.erb" file, but that didn't seem to do anything.

So, my question is: Even with these precautions, why do the number of open connections continue to increase? How do I fix it so that connections are closed once the calculation is completed?

I should lastly note that the Heroku-provided PSQL database I am using supports a maximum of 20 open connections at once.

If I need to provide more info/code, just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

`Database#disconnect` does not disconnect connections currently being used by other threads, so if another thread is using the connection when you are calling it (likely in a multi-threaded app), it won't disconnect those connections.

There are a maximum of 4 database connections per `Sequel::Database` object by default, so unless you are running more than 5 app processes, you should be able to stay under Heroku's 20 connection limit without any manual disconnections.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be due to DB connections not falling back? I have not worked with Sequel, but seems like you may have to add middleware to your stack
I had similar issue in active record where connections were getting exhausted, to overcome it I had to add

```
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
```

Of course for you it would be something else for Sequel.

Comment: Hmm, when you say "DB connections not falling back," what do you mean? I'm still a novice at PSQL, so I'm not quite sure about it yet.

Comment: I have not worked on Sequel API so I am not sure. In ActiveRecord, it was holding on to the DB connections from the pool. So if the Pool size was 5, after 5 calls application would stall.

Answer (score 1):

Don't open and close the connection like that. Open the connection to the database at the top of the app (not in before) and don't close it.

Ruby apps run as one process so no need to open and close it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if I open a connection at the top of the app (outside the before loop), wouldn't that leave open a connection to the PSQL? In Heroku, a max of 20 open connections is allowed on the free PSQL database I'm using. If the number of open connections would not increase, can you please tell me why they wouldn't?

Comment: Also, do you know if there is a way I can test whether or not the app will crash if a bunch of people try using it?

Comment: Not sure of the why, but it works ok for me, I have a site on Heroku using one Dyno and the free psql, I have my psql connection outside the before (using datamapper) and it works perfectly. No issues even when on the hacker news homepage and getting over 100 concurrent users.

Comment: To test you can run a simple load test. Take a look at https://www.blitz.io/, it's also a Heroku add-on.